# Determine if the series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln(k))^{\ln(\ln(k))}}$ diverges or converges

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Determine if the series $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln(k))^{\ln(\ln(k))}}$$ diverges or converges.

---

My Attempt:

So, I claim that this series diverges. We know that:

$$\ln(x) \leq x-1$$

$$\implies \ln(x+1) \leq x$$

$$\implies 1+x \leq e^x$$

So, we can see that $$e^{-x} \geq 1-x$$. Now, we know that:

$$\frac{1}{(\ln(k))^{\ln(\ln(k))}} = \exp(-(\ln(\ln(k)))^2) \geq 1-\ln(\ln(k))^2$$

The series with the general term on the right does not converge. Hence, by comparison, we conclude that our given series does not converge. $\Box$

Does the above argument work? If it doesn't, why? How can I fix it?

**Edit:**

I've just realized that this doesn't work because comparison can only really be used for two positive series. So, not really sure where to go from here with regards to this haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with your approach is you only obtain $-\infty$ as a lower bound on positive terms, which doesn't tell is whether their $k\to\infty$ limit is $0$. In fact it is, so we can't use that to tell whether the series diverges.

A better argument, using $x^2\ll e^x$ for sufficiently large $x$: the denominator is $e^{\ln^2\ln k}\ll e^{\ln k}=k$, so a comparison with the harmonic series proves divergence.

Comment: Wait, so does my argument actually work? I was under the impression that it didn't since I'm not using comparison correctly?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats Yours doesn't; I've added a paragraph clarifying that.

Comment: Alright thank you very much, I understand now.

Comment: @J.G. $e^{\ln^2\ln k}\ll e^{\ln k}=k$ This is not correct. As for sufficiently large $x$, this part will be the greatest $e^{\ln^2\ln k}$, unless the answer is communicated very poorly.

Comment: @TeodorasPaura My point, in case it was poorly communicated, is that for all sufficiently large $k$, $(\ln\ln k)^2\ll\ln k$ so $\exp(-(\ln\ln k)^2)\gg1/k$, which proves the series diverges. Perhaps using $\ln^2$ to indicate a logarithm's square was an issue.

Comment: @J.G. ah, yes makes sense, yes I misunderstood. :) Though I am a tad unsure why this expression is true $(\ln\ln k)^2\ll\ln k$

Comment: @TeodorasPaura Let $x=\ln\ln k$. As $k\to\infty$, $x\to\infty$ so $x^2e^{-x}\to0$.

Comment: hmm @J.G. I got the same but for some reason, I find it a little confusing, thank you!